# How can I get images from "assets/resource/mat "?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some images in "assets/resource/mat" . I want to get this images and put them to array . But when I try to get this images I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException . I think that there is problem with Resource.LoadAll("mat") method . But I can't fix it . Please help me

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string t;
    public Sprite[] Icons;

    void Start()
    {
        Object[] loadedIcons = Resources.LoadAll("mat");
        Icons = new Sprite[loadedIcons.Length];

        for (int x = 0; x < loadedIcons.Length; x++)
        { 
            Icons[x] = (Sprite)loadedIcons[x];
            Debug.Log("Loading....");
        }

         GameObject sp = new GameObject();
         sp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Icons[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: The Resources folder should have a capital letter at its start "assets/Resources/mat"

Comment: I change it to assets/Resources/mat , but it still doesn't work . :(

Comment: I didn't mean the path in your code but the actual name of the folder in your project needs to start with a captial letter. also you need to cast the type of object you are loading from Resources. Check Unity docs for more information on casting the type.

Comment: The folder in my project starts with a capital letter , friend . I'm new in unity and it's hard for me to fix errors :( (It still doesn't work :( )

Answer (score 0):

Loading all images from a particular folder, with LINQ, would look like this...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class Four : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public Sprite[] icons;

    void Start()
    {
        icons= Resources.LoadAll("met", typeof(Sprite)).Cast<Sprite>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess you instead of `Sprite` first have to load a `Texture2D` and then create a `Sprite` from it.

Also note you used `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()` on a newly created empty GameObject so obviously there will never be a `SpriteRenderer` component attached. Instead use [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html).

```
Sprite[] Icons;
Texture2D LoadedTextures;

private void Start()
{
    LoadedTextures = (Texture2D[])Resources.LoadAll("mat", typeof(Texture2D));
    Icons = new Sprite[loadedIcons.Length];

    for (int x = 0; x < loadedIcons.Length; x++)
    { 
        Icons[x] = Sprite.Create(
            LoadedTextures[x], 
            new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, LoadedTextures[x].width, LoadedTextures[x].height), 
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 
            100.0f);
    }

     GameObject sp = new GameObject();

     // Note that here you created a new empty GameObject
     // so it obviously won't have any component of type SpriteRenderer
     // so add it instead of GetComponent
     sp.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Icons[0];
}
```